# Encrypt PDF document using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, encryption, itext

I want to make my PDF document protected by not allowing fill in and copy from it. I am using iTextSharp for this. I have following code:

```
  PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(document, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(PASSWORD));
  using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
  {
      using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, ms))
      {
           stamper.SetEncryption(
               null,
               Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(PASSWORD),
               PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING,
               PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_128);
      }
  }

  reader.Close();
```

When the document is generated I use that code to encrypt the document. But later when I open the document in Adobe Reader (tested on 9 and 11) and check the 'File > Properties > Security' their are no restrictions applied on fill in and copy of the document and their status is Allowed.

Is there any issue in that code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [ITextSharp documentation for `PdfStamper`](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfStamper.html), the second parameter to this method is an output stream representing the destination for the encrypted PDF document data. The code you show in the question simply disposes the `MemoryStream` after you setup the encryption so any changes this code could apply to your PDF document will never be saved to disk or otherwise be available outside your application.

Comment: thanks @M.Babcock you are right. The issue is resolved. I can see the Not Allowed status against all the options now. One point still not clear that Pdf properties showing 'Not Allowed' with 'Copy content' option but I can still able to copy text from some of the fields (not all fields).