# Encrypt PDF with password using iTextSharp while downloading the file from browser Default Viewer

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, itext

I need to encrypt the pdf file in such a manner that when the user tries to open the pdf file through the application, user should be able to view the document without entering the password (i.e., the password should be passed programmatically). Also, when user tries to download the same file from the browser and opens the downloaded file, it should ask the encrypted password to open the file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21213849/encrypt-pdf-document-using-itextsharp

Comment: Define the application in the sentence: "when user tries to open the pdf file through application." Is that application a third party application such as Adobe Reader, or is it an application you are writing? Also: be aware that password protection in PDF is flawed. I'd consider certificate encryption instead.

Comment: @ Bruno Lowagie : The Question was totally different from the one you compare as duplicated.Actual question is "Encrypt PDF with password using iTextSharp while downloading the file from browser Default Viewer"